# Make my own setter in mongoose who change two fields

Tags: mongoose

I would like to make a custom function in mongoose for change two fields at the same time. In my case I want to make a function `setStatus(val)`. This function will change the status of the current model and `push` this value in a array of log like this :

```
setStatus(val) {
   this.status = val;
   this.statusLogs.push({
      date: new Date(),
      status: val
   })
}
```

I see there is `methods` and `statics` but I think it's not what I needed...

Comment: What's wrong with [methods](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/methods-statics.html) ? Another option is to attach a [setter](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/getters-setters.html) on your `status` field.

Comment: With this way I can change value of my model properly ? It's not just for make particular query ?

Comment: In the first case, you would have to do `doc.setStatus(value)` whereas in the second case you would have to do `doc.set({ status: value })` or `Model.create({ status: value })` to trigger the setter. To run it with a query, you would have to use [runSettersOnQuery](http://thecodebarbarian.com/mongoose-4.10-runSettersOnQuery-option.html) option.

Comment: This work like a charm ! Thank you. I don't know if you want post an answer or if I have to delete this question... Let me know.